# How to use Reactor (Spring WebClient) to do a repeat call?

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am using Reactor (Spring5 WebClient)  as my reactive programming API. I have 2 REST endpoint to call. The result of the first one will be the parameter to the second one. For the second API, it will return a result with "hasMore" value. If this value is **true**, I should change the pagination parameters and call the second API again. The demo code is the following:

```
 client.getApi1()
        .map(r -> r.getResult())
        .flatMap(p -> client.getApi2(p, 2(page size), 1(page start)))
        .subscribe(r -> System.out.println(r.isHasmore()));
```

How to repeat calling the second API (getApi2) until "hasMore" is false.

Besides, I need to change the parameters page size and page start

Comment: _"I need to change the parameters page size and page start"_ How?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this code:

```
 AtomicInteger pageCounter = new AtomicInteger(0);
 client.getApi1()
    .map(r -> r.getResult())
    .flatMap(p -> client.getApi2(p, 2(page size), pageCounter.incrementAndGet()))
    .repeat()            
    .takeWhile(r -> r.isHasmore())
    .subscribe(r -> System.out.println(r.isHasmore()));
```

`repeat()` calls *getApi2* infinitely.
`takeWhile(continuePredicate)` relays values while a *continuePredicate (`r.isHasmore()`)* returns **true**

Comment: how to change page size and page start ?

Comment: Use AtomicInteger class, init it before your client and call .incrementAndGet() method for changing page number.

Comment: unfortunately pageCounter.incrementAndGet() doesn't work for me. It's always 1

Comment: @moldovean is .flatmap called?  because pageCounter.incrementAndGet() should work correctly

Answer (score 2):

I find a solution by use expand operator. But, need to do some change on my API call. The response from the `getApi2` need to return last page size and last page start.

```
    client.getApi1()
        .map(r -> r.getResult())
        .getApi2(p, 2, 1)
        .expand(res -> {
            if (res.isHasmore()) {
                return client.getApi2(orgId, res.getPageSize(), res.PageStart() + 1);
            }
            return Flux.empty();
        });
```