# How to delay repeated WebClient get request

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am using the Spring 5 WebClient to repeatedly fetch some state of a running process from a REST api.

With help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52250893/how-to-use-reactor-spring-webclient-to-do-a-repeat-call) I for now came to this solution:

```
webClient.get().uri(...).retrieve.bodyToMono(State.class)
          .repeat()
          .skipUntil(state -> stateFinished())
          .limitRequest(1)
          .subscribe(state -> {...});
```

While this works, the get request is fired at a very high rate. What would be the right way to limit the request rate to let's say 1 request per second?

I tried using `delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1))` but that only delays the results, not the request itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `repeatWhen` operator with your custom implementation of the companion `Publisher`

```
Mono.just("test")
        .repeatWhen(longFlux -> Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1)))
        .take(5)
        .log()
        .blockLast();
```

or with `Repeate` function from the [reactor-addons](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-addons)

```
Mono.just("test")
        .repeatWhen(Repeat.times(Long.MAX_VALUE)
                .fixedBackoff(Duration.ofSeconds(1)))
        .take(5)
        .log()
        .blockLast();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another little workaround in your case where you zip each of your call with a Flux used as a limiter.

```
.zipWith(Flux.interval(Duration.of(1, ChronoUnit.SECONDS)))
```

Although I would have thought that the `delayElements()` works maybe you didn't put it on the correct stage of your Webclient stack.

Answer (score 0):

That you are using `delayElements` tells me you are putting it after the repeat. What you want to delay is the subscription to the WebClient.

```
webClient
      .get()
      .uri(...)
      .retrieve
      .bodyToMono(State.class)
      .delaySubscription(Duration.ofSeconds(1)) //Just add this before the repeat
      .repeat()
      .skipUntil(state -> stateFinished())
      .limitRequest(1)
      .subscribe(state -> {...});
```

Doing this ensures that there is a second between the response of the nth request and the triggering of the n+1th request. If you need fixed frequency of calls irrespective of the time taken by each request to response, wrap your code with a `Flux.interval` as suggested by Roman.

Comment: That would delay the first request as well.

Answer (score 0):

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56528298/8596440) the best suited for a similar problem I was facing.

```
getJobStatus()
.repeatWhen(completed -> completed.delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(pollDelay))) //(1)
.takeUntil(JobStatus::isDone) //(2)
.last() //(3)
```

Answer (score -1):

Alternative solution to your problem

```
Flux.interval(Duration.ZERO, Duration.ofSeconds(1))
        .onBackpressureDrop()
        .concatMap(i -> webClientCall(...), 1)
        //or flatMap() if you want send request each second
        .filter(state -> stateFinished(state))
        .next()
        .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(...))
        //
        .subscribe(state -> {...});
```

But remember, if you subscribe by your self (not by Spring) then reactor Subscriber Context would not be propagated to your request (no security context, sleuth, etc...)