# How do you implement Polling Logic in Project Reactor?

Tags: spring, project-reactor

I have a method that sends a request to get the status of a job and returns the status, it looks like this:

`Mono<JobStatus> getJobStatus() {...}`

The `JobStatus` object has a method `JobStatus.isDone()` which returns whether the pending job is done or not.

Is there a way for me to keep subscribing to the mono until `JobStatus.isDone()` is true? i.e. something like `getJobStatus().keepSubscribingUntil(status -> status.isDone())`

Comment: ```getJobStatus()``` will wait for the next signal to invoke the subscriber. Reactor is all about push model than pull, so it works out of the box

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One option would be for the `getJobStatus()` `Mono` to only emit when the job is done, which might not necessarily be easy depending on how that `Mono` is currently implemented.

For polling, **assuming the `Mono` polls each time you subscribe to it** you could use `repeatWhen` paired with `takeUntil`:

```
getJobStatus()
    .repeatWhen(completed -> completed.delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(pollDelay))) //(1)
    .takeUntil(JobStatus::isDone) //(2)
    .last() //(3)
```

(1) repeatedly re-subscribe to the source `Mono` (this produces a `Flux<JobStatus>`)

(2) cancel the above repeat cycle as soon as the returned status is marked as done

(3) switch back to a `Mono<JobStatus>` which emits the last iteration's status (so the one that is marked as done)

Comment: Thanks for your expertise; this solution is great. We'll also investigate your first suggestion if its possible to only emit when the job is done.

Comment: Hey, regarding the `.repeatWhen(...)` line, should it be: `.repeatWhen(completed -> completed.delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(pollDelay))` instead? I.e. the flux inside the repeatWhen must emit many elements, rather than just have a Mono.delay which will emit something only once?

Comment: @CowZow just came back to this answer and came to the same conclusion as you :) better late than never, I've fixed it

Comment: @SimonBaslé how should one time out the polling after say 'x' seconds or 'n' times to prevent infinite loop?

Answer (score 2):

Other option would be using **repeatWhenEmpty** when you might want to poll till you get either success or failure from the publisher. When there are scenarios you don't want to wait forever to get the response, rather want to have a timeout, you could use the same method where you have own logic or libraries' method to timeout the operation.

```
AtomicInteger c = new AtomicInteger();
Mono<String> source = Mono.defer(() -> c.getAndIncrement() < 3 
? Mono.empty() 
: Mono.just("7"));
return source.repeatWhenEmpty(4, Flux::cache);
```

In the above example 4 specifies, maximum number of times you want to retry.

```
source.repeatWhenEmpty(exponentialBackOff(Duration.ofMillis(1), 
                Duration.ofMillis(15),
                Duration.ofSeconds(1)));
```

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-java-client has the exponentialBackOff utils mehtod.