# How to turn a polling api into reactive stream

Tags: java, project-reactor

Say I have an function that has the following signature:

```
class Item {
  String name;
  Long id;
}
public Flux<Item> getNew(long id);
```

`getNew()` returns a stream of items added after id (0..N). So how do I turn this into an infinite stream?

So something like this:

```
public Flux<Item> observe(long id) {
    return Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1)).
             flatMap(counter -> getNew(id)); // <-- how to use last value from getNew flux as the new id                
}
```

The only way I was able to do it was with some type of state variable:

```
   public Flux<Long> observe(long id) {
     final AtomicLong last = new AtomicLong(id);
     return Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1)).
         flatMap(l -> getNew(last.get())).
         doOnNext(last::set);    
   }
```

Is there a more idiomatic way to do this? I tried to create generator for this, but I'm can't figure out how to implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can identify the last `Item` emitted by `getNew` by inspecting it, then you can use the [`.expand`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#expand-java.util.function.Function-) operator:

```java
    public Flux<Item> observe(long id) {
        return getNew(id)
                .expand(item -> isLast(item)
                        ? getNew(item.id)
                        : Flux.empty());
    }
    /**
     * @return true if the given item is the last item emitted by getNew
     */
    private boolean isLast(Item item) {
        return // ... snip ...
    }
```

If you cannot identify the last `Item` by inspecting it, then you'll have to use a state variable.  Although, I'd recommend using [`.defer`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#defer-java.util.function.Supplier-) and [`.repeat`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#repeat--) instead of  `.interval`...

```java
    public Flux<Item> observe(long id) {
        final AtomicLong nextStartId = new AtomicLong(id);
        return Flux.defer(() -> getNew(nextStartId.get()))
                .doOnNext(item -> nextStartId.set(item.id))
                .repeat();
    }
```

The main reason against using [`.interval`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#interval-java.time.Duration-) is because:

> If demand is not produced in time, an onError will be signalled

Therefore, if the API takes too long, or processing the results takes too long, the stream will end with an error.  This might not be a problem with long intervals, but with relatively short intervals (like 1 second from your example), this could be a problem.

If you want to delay before each repeat iteration, then you can use `.repeatWhen`, with reactor-extra's [`Repeat`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/extra/snapshot/api/reactor/retry/Repeat.html) with a fixed backoff.  This will give you "fixed delay" semantics, instead of "fixed interval".

Comment: I can identify the Item only by the fact it's the last one in the stream. What would the benefit of using defer/repeat? Mind you the getNew is polling, I need to call it periodically.

Comment: Updated answer to include disadvantage of using `.interval`

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54606011/26734) has the backoff for the curious.

Comment: what would happen if the `repeat()` was placed inside of the `defer()`?