# Is there a way to update a local variable through Mono.fromCallable()'s return value of an api inside a while loop?

Tags: java, mono, callable

I need to run GET requests multiple times until the return of the GET is an empty array.
Currently I have been doing it with a global receivedAllApiData variable I update in getApiValues if it is an empty array. However I need to find a way to do this in the method locally. Is there a way the mono.fromCallable could change a local variable?

```
while (!receivedAllApiData && offsetAmount < MAX_REQUEST_FALLBACK) {
            int offset = offset;
            Mono.fromCallable(() -> Api.getApiValues(Id, offset, LIMIT, property))
                    .map(this::getApiValues)
                    .subscribe(this::buildStructure, this::ErrorCounter);
            offsetAmount += LIMIT;
        }
```

maybe there is a better way to run several calls?

Comment: Is there a good reason why you are using `Mono.fromCallable`? This isn't reactive code, and you're not calling (natively) reactive code. Why not just call `Api.getApiValues(Id, offset, LIMIT, property);` directly in a try/catch block?

Comment: code procedure / and we need it to be async as well.

Comment: To be fully reactive you would need to rewrite all the surrounding code (the while loop) as well. That could involve using `takeWhile`, such as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52250893/how-to-use-reactor-spring-webclient-to-do-a-repeat-call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an atomicBoolean you can update the value inside the map function as below.

```
       AtomicBoolean receivedAllApiData = new AtomicBoolean(false);

        while (!!receivedAllApiData.get() && offsetAmount < MAX_REQUEST_FALLBACK) {
            int offset = offsetAmount;
            Mono.fromCallable(() -> Api.getApiValues(Id, offset, LIMIT, property))
                    .map(listOfValues -> {
                        List<Values> nonNullListOfValues = CollectionUtils.isEmpty(listOfValues) ? emptyList() : listOfValues;
                        receivedAllApiData.set(nonNullListOfValues.isEmpty());
                        return nonNullListOfValues;
                    })
                    .subscribe(this::buildStructure, this::ErrorCounter);
            offsetAmount += LIMIT;
        }
```